# How to use radio buttons in repeating form group

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a repeating form field inside the SAME FORM. I have my input form field named as an array e.g. `first_name[]`, `gender[]`.

In this case when a radio button is clicked then it affects radio buttons of other repeated form groups.

```js
$('#repeatButton ').on('click', function() {
  var repeater = $('#repeater .items').clone();
  $('#repeater').append(repeater);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="repeater">
    <div class="form-group items">
      <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender[]"><label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender[]"><label>Female</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input value="add" id="repeatButton">
</form>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I made it different by adding numbers to an array. But the problem occurs when I had to remove any items from the middle of the form. 

P.S. I also have remove functionality

Comment: Can you please add that logic to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Checkboxes are grouped by the `name` attribute. As such you need to make the `name` unique within each `#repeater .items` group. The simplest way to do that in your case would be to append a timestamp to the value.

Note that you should only `clone()` the first group, not all of them, and also use a `button` to trigger the addition of the new elements. I'd wrapped the radios in the `label` elements to allow users to click the associated text too. Try this:

```js
$('#repeatButton ').on('click', function() {
  var $repeater = $('#repeater .items:first').clone();
  var ts = (new Date()).getTime();
  $repeater.find('input').attr('name', function(i, name) {
    return ts + '_' + name;
  });
  $repeater.appendTo('#repeater');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="repeater">
    <div class="form-group items">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender[]" />
        Male
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender[]" />
        Female
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="repeatButton">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So how to perform the update on my server after post request. How will I know which radio button belong to which form group?

Comment: In that case you would need to keep track of the group id and apply it to the `name` of all input fields within that group.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this.

```js
$('#repeatButton ').on('click', function() {
  var repeater = $('#repeater .items:first').clone();
  $('#repeater').append(repeater);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="repeater">
    <div class="form-group items">
      <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender[]"><label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender[]"><label>Female</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input value="add" id="repeatButton">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#repeatButton ').on('click', function() {
  var repeater = $('#repeater .items:first').html();
  repeater = repeater+"<BR>"; 
  $('#repeater').append(repeater);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="repeater">
    <div class="form-group items">
      <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender[]"><label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender[]"><label>Female</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input value="add" id="repeatButton">
</form>
```